# DPRP is disabled for this merchant for paypalpro using directpayment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

My problem is that DPRP is disabled for this merchant in my sandbox business account `soumik10@yahoo.co.in`

Error showing while using dodirectpayment classic api: `DPRP is disabled for this merchant`

Next URL is executed:

https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=soumik10_api1.yahoo.co.in&PWD=1401520404&SIGNATURE=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AmWfDfsaKco4X7iAvZ0ed2jFrfuN&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&PROFILESTARTDATE=2012-05-11T00:00:00Z&DESC=test&description&BILLINGPERIOD=Day&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1&AMT=10&MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=3&ACCT=6011746396125231&CREDITCARDTYPE=Discover&CVV2=123&&CVV2=123&FIRSTNAME=James&LASTNAME=Smith&STREET=FirstStreet&CITY=SanJose&STATE=CA&ZIP=95131&COUNTRYCODE=US&CURRENCYCODE=USD&EXPDATE=052015

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox account doesn't have recurring payments enabled. try this:

1. Log into the sandbox (sandbox.paypal.com) using the new test account
2. Make sure you are in the My Account section of the site by clicking the My Account main menu tab
3. Click on the sub menu "Profile"
4. Under the Financial Information column click the link for "Recurring payments dashboard"
5. On the right hand side click the link for "Sign up for Recurring Payments"
6. Click the Agree and Continue button

You should also be aware that PayPal Payments Pro and Recurring Payments is only available in certain markets.

Comment: Hi KevinG , i tried your way but i didnt get solution , they are giving this message => "Thanks for your interest
Thanks for your interest in Enhanced Recurring Payments. At this time, the service is not available to your account.

Fortunately, we offer another great solution for recurring payments. You can sign up for a recurring payments service specifically designed for PayPal Payments Pro."

Comment: right...ERP is for PayPal Payments Standard accounts. "You can sign up for a recurring payments service specifically designed for PayPal Payments Pro." <= this is what you want.

Comment: Hey KevinG , i'm novice to this , my requirement is to use credit card transaction from my site using paypal , So i have used paypal pro directpayment , it is working fine but when i use  direct payment for recurinf subscription then problem arises , showing DPRP not enabled ,I have provided the url which i'm using for testing is given in my first post over here . I need help on this.

Comment: PayPal tech support will have to enable the feature in your sandbox account. One option is to file a support ticket [here](https://www.paypal.com/mts). (click on "Contact Technical Support") Request they enable DPRP in the sandbox account. Give them the sandbox account's email address. OR post the sandbox account email address here and I will try to enable it for you tomorrow.

Comment: also, as I stated in my original answer, PayPal Payments Pro and Recurring Payments is only available in certain markets, specifically US, CA, and UK. Be sure the account is based in one of these countries.

Comment: My sandbox account country is US  and also that account is BusinesPro

Comment: @Soumik can I reach you by  email at email address above? Would like to send you an email.

Comment: Yes you can reach me => soumik10@yahoo.co.in